# ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When I try to delete something from my inventory database, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in InventoriesController#destroy

SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "inventories" WHERE "inventories"."id" = ?
```

In the terminal, it says

```
{"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"dBNU2GkV0+rOcp4NVEljm4oIpkdOnPsvZKdmisaadBzX3QkY1VwurZNRPL0WFtVvizeAcJb7H6E50ObmpRsXAg==", "id"=>"1"}
```

It also says the source is at:

```
 def destroy
    @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
    @inventory.destroy

    redirect_to inventory_path
end
```

In my inventories file which is:

```
class InventoriesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
     end

    def index
        @inventories = Inventory.all
    end

    def new
        @inventory = Inventory.new
    end

    def create
        @inventory = Inventory.new(inventory_params)


        if @inventory.save
        redirect_to @inventory
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
        if @inventory.update(inventory_params)
            redirect_to @inventory
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
        @inventory.destroy

        redirect_to inventory_path
    end
end

private 
def inventory_params
    params.require(:inventory).permit(:product_name, :brand_name, :item_id, :upc_code, :color, :department, :size, :condition, :fabric_type, :shipping_weight, :sku, :asin, :quantity, :cost_price, :sell_price, :key_product_features, :product_description, :search_terms, :status, :listing_in_usa, :listing_in_canada, :listing_in_mexico)

end
```

Comment: You have a relationship between `Inventory` and `Item`, you need to deal with that and/or to specify the `destroy` `dependency` within your relationships.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there is a foreign key to the inventories table from another one, which you would expect to see expressed in the Inventory model with a `has_many` or `has_one` relationship.

The fixes would be to either have the foreign key configured to automatically delete the child records, or to specify `dependent: :destroy` on the association.

The former would be very fast, but would not allow callbacks on the child instances to execute, so I'd recommend the `:destroy` option.